# With Spring, how can I inject a child bean in a parent bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Bean that wants to inject its child classes like so:

Parent:

```
package test;

@Component
public class Parent {
  @Autowired
  Child child;

  public Child getChild() {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Child:

```
package test;

@Component
public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [test.Child] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency
```

Removing the `extends Parent` bit causes everything to work as expected, so it looks like Spring is unable to find the Child, as though the Parent is shadowing it somehow. How do I configure Spring to correctly wire these child instances? I'm using Java Class Configuration, like the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "test")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

I have tried playing around with the `@Qualifier` annotation and assigning distinct names within `AppConfig` as in the following, which did not help:

```
@Bean(name = "parent")
public Parent parent() {
  return new Parent();
}

@Bean(name = "child")
public Child child() {
  return new Child();
}
```

I'm not sure what the missing ingredient is in order to make Spring see the Child class as its own distinct entity. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by modifying Parent's definition as follows:

```
package test;

@Primary
@Component
public class Parent {
  @Resource
  Child child;

  public Child getChild() {
    return child;
  }
}
```

And also modifying the child as follows:

```
package test;

@Component("child")
public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

I have replaced the `@Autowired` annotation with `@Resource`, which attempts a lookup by name before type, and added an explicit name to the child class. In order to disambiguate the parent from the child when attempting to autowire the parent, I have also added the `@Primary` annotation to the parent.

I still do not fully understand why the lookup by type fails, forcing me to use `@Resource` to look up the bean by name instead.

Comment: This fails for me, @user108471, with the initial error; I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 & JDK 8 which uses Spring 4.2.5 on Linux.

Comment: @JanNielsen Sorry, it looks like I left out another, crucial, change: adding an explicit name to the child class.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Child` extends `Parent`, a `Parent` must be constructed to construct a `Child` but a `Parent` requires a `Child` for construction. This is a circular dependency; avoid creating circular dependencies in your code.

You will need to refactor your code. This may not be possible in your code-base, but if you can invert the relationship so `Parent` extends `Child` (instead of the reverse as you have it now), you'll be able to inject:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Autowired
    private Parent parent;
    @Bean
    Child makeChild() { return new Child(); }
}
@Component
class Parent extends Child {
    @Autowired
    private Child child;

    public Child getChild() { return this.child; }
}
class Child {
}
```

Alternatively, refactor the code that both `Child` and `Parent` need into another class and inject that code into the `Parent` and `Child`:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Autowired
    private Parent parent;
    @Bean
    Child makeChild() { return new Child(); }
    @Bean
    Shared makeShared() { return new Shared(); }
}
@Component
class Parent {
    @Autowired
    private Shared shared;
    @Autowired
    private Child child;
    public Child getChild() { return this.child; }
}
class Child {
    @Autowired
    private Shared shared;
}
class Shared {
}
```

Comment: Please forgive me, but I'm not understanding the part of your code snippet that actually solves the problem. I see that you have removed the `@Component` annotation on Child, but doing the same on mine changes nothing. You've also created a new class and omitted one of the classes in my question, and I'm unclear how that changes the solution.

Comment: I missed the `extends Parent` on the `Child` - this creates a circular dependency which is why you're seeing this problem. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Looks like I glanced right past that omission as well.

Comment: I don't think the circular dependency is the cause of this problem. I can easily create two classes that autowire each other without issue, and I've discovered I can avoid this error by changing the `@Autowired` annotation to `@Resource`. That implies the problem has to do with the type lookup itself, doesn't it?